# How to output CSS to the beginning of the stylesheet in a Wordpress Plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I'm trying to insert some CSS at the very top of the Current Theme Stylesheet via plugin.  (So that the CSS is easily over-ridden by the plugin user).

How would you prepend CSS to the Theme Stylesheet?

Also i'm trying to put some Javascript just before the /body tag in the theme, how would that be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never modify the current theme's stylesheet via a plugin. What if the theme gets updated, or the user changes themes? Not a good idea. Instead, you should have the plugin create a custom css file, which could be located anywhere you wish, even inside of the current theme's folder.

The only way to output info just before `</body>` tag is by hooking into `wp_footer()`, but this will not always result in the content being output just before the `</body>` tag, since themes will often place the `wp_footer()` function within a DIV tag, or higher up in the footer. If you absolutely must output something just before the `</body>` tag, I would use jQuery to insert it. You could easily setup the content or HTML that is outputted with [wp_localize_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

If you are okay with the content/HTML not necessarily being immediately before the `</body>` tag, then use the `wp_footer()` method, which is what I recommend:

```
function your_custom_content_function() {
    echo 'this is outputted in the footer';
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'your_custom_content_function');
```

Comment: Is there a way to include the new stylesheet right after the <head> or preferrably right after the </title>?  All I really care about with the CSS is adding the CSS above the Theme CSS Include so that the plugin user doesn't have to use CSS over-rides to create the CSS they want.  I think That wp_footer function will work great.

Comment: It depends, again, on the theme. If the theme has used wp_enqueue_script() to load the CSS file, then you can easily load yours before, but if the theme simply has the CSS loaded via &lt;link&gt; in the header, then there is no way to guarantee it comes before.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to register and output javascript and you should always use [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) to register and output CSS. Both of those links to codex pages provide good code snippet examples. Make sure that you hook the functions to the right action, as WordPress 3.3+ throws a warning if you hook it to actions that run too early.

If you want CSS to take precedence over a theme stylesheet, then you want those styles to be added to the `<head>` *after* the theme stylesheet. If two CSS selectors are identical, the one that comes *second* takes precedence. Because `wp_enqueue_styles()` gets fired as part of `wp_head()` which is supposed to be the last thing in the `<head>`, using that shouldn't be a problem, even if the theme registers their stylesheet by putting it elsewhere in the `<head>`.

`wp_enqueue_scripts()` has an $in_footer argument that lets you print the script at the end of the document. As mentioned elsewhere, you can't guarantee where a theme puts their call to `wp_footer`, but that's pretty much all you can do.